# Why my code is wrong?:A simple conversion of number systems

Tags: c++

OJ result :partial accepted

---

Description
Put n balls into 50 boxes numbered 0, 1, 2, ......, 49, (n<250) and require that the ith box must contain pi times (m to the i-th power) of balls, or none if the box cannot satisfy this condition. Where 2 <= m <= 16 and pi is an integer between 0 and m - 1. Find a specific solution for releasing the balls.

---

The input file has only one line, just n and m, separated by an empty space.

---

The output file has several rows, each with two values, first the number of the box and the number of balls in the box, and if there are no balls in the box then no output, but output in ascending order of the box number.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYs8J.png)

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
long long n,m;

    cin>>n>>m;
    
    
    for(int i=0;i<=50;i++){
    
    if(n%m){
        long long x=(long long)(pow(m,i));
        
        cout<<i<<" "<<n%m*x<<endl;
        
    }   
    n=n/m; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide an example for your input.  Provide an example of your output.   Then provide an example of what the output should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potential errors in the code include:

- The problem statement specifies there are 50 boxes, numbered 0 to 49, but the code loops over 51 boxes, numbered 0 to 50, with `for(int i=0;i<=50;i++)`.
- `pow` should not be used for integer exponentiation because it is inefficient in this use, presents overflow and precision issues, and some low-quality implementations of `pow` do not return a correct result even when the result is exactly representable. For example, `pow(10, 3)` might return 999.9999999999998863131622783839702606201171875, after which conversion to `long long` produces 999.
- The `long long` type may overflow.